# Localize android app

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services, signed-apk

I have 2 string resources in my project. Hindi and English. And it changes dynamically in app itself. I want to launch my application in hindi although default language of device is English.

If I change default language in play console to hindi then dose application launch in hindi?

Or I have to write code for same?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

It's really work... fa=Persian... en=English...
enter your language code in languageToLoad :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String languageToLoad  = "fa"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply... What about Google play console localization?

Comment: if locale is Hindi, you can set  languageToLoad  = "hi"

Comment: Above code only change language of single activity.. All other activities remain same.. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

This isn't handled by the Play console, you have to write code in your app.
Localization in the Play console is for your app listing in the Play Store.